# notice trying to get property in php when sql returns 0 row

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to check if the stockid/s exist in peri or nonperi tbl. If the stockid belongs to peri, then I want to update peri. If not, the nonperi table will be updated.

What I did was to check first in the nonperi table and if the result is 0, then search again on nonperi tbl. Here is my code

```
//update nonperi table
        $qryup = "UPDATE nonperi
                    SET bal='$balafter',modifiedby='$userid', modifiedon='$currdate'
                    WHERE stockid= $item";
        $mysql1 = $conn->query($qryup); 
        if ($mysql1-> num_rows == 0)
        {
            //else if not in nonperi, update peri tbl instead
            $qryup2 = "UPDATE peri
                    SET bal='$balafter',modifiedby='$userid', modifiedon='$currdate'
                    WHERE stockid= $item";
            $mysql2 = $conn->query($qryup2);    
        }
```

The code works, it updates the nonperi if the result from peri tbl is 0, however, the notice of property obj etc is still displayed.

Do you have any suggestion on how to make this work, or any workaround or if you have any better code to achieve this without the error? PLease help. THanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going with a prepared statement instead? I know I never had any notice when using those instead of directly query:

```
$qryup = "UPDATE nonperi
         SET bal=:bal,modifiedby=:userid, modifiedon=:currdate
        WHERE stockid= :id";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($qryup); 
$stmt->bindValue(":bal", $balafter);
$stmt->bindValue(":userid", $userid);
$stmt->bindValue(":currdate", $currdate);
$stmt->bindValue(":id", $item);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0)
{
    //similar treatment here
}
```